# What, of reciting Quran at the grave, is permissible?

Tags: quran-recitation, death

A friend of mine has recently had a bereavement, and some of their family have suggested the husband of the sister who passed away spend 40 days going to the grave and reading them Quran.

Whilst my initial research brought up varied accounts on the permissibility of reciting quran *at all* in the cemetery. As well as this I have read some Sheikhs considering any formal remembrance of the dead to be Ibadah.

I am unsure on how to advise my friend. What of this is allowed?

Comment: which view do u want? This is a contemporary 'made up' issue. All u can do is check if this is allowed ( in the sect of urs). Else, following the prescribed sunnah is the most advisable, i. e. Making tons of du'a for them...

Comment: @servent-of-wiser my main concern is the number prescribed to this.  Add I say in my question, this is the part that sounds like innovation. Anything that prohibits making up a number of times to do a thing would be sufficient.

Answer (score 2):

Imam Ash-Shafi'i and his followers said that recitation of the Qur'an will not be up to the corpse. Because it is not a charity nor its bodies, and Rasulullah SAW never ordered to his ummah, nor advocate, or guiding him, both with *nash* and cues. And never quoted also from a shahabah. Even if it was any good, they have preceded it. And chapter Al-Qurubat (worship) is limited to *nash* (arguments), do not apply to him qiyas and ra'yu. As for prayer and charity, it has been agreed upon the arrival of the bodies, and indicated by the Shari'a texts ". (Tafsir Ibn Kathir, 7/356-357, tahqiq Haani Al-Haj).

Wallahu a'lam

Answer (score 0):

The prophet PBUH used to frequently visit the graves. He additionally used to made Duaa for them on said graves saying:

> “Al-salaamu ‘alaykum ahl al-diyaar min al-mu’mineen wa’l-Muslimeen, wa inna in sha Allaah bikum laahiqoon, nas’al Allaaha lana wa lakum al-‘aafiyah
>
> (Peace be upon you, O people of the dwellings, believers and Muslims. If Allaah wills we will join you. We ask Allaah to grant us and you safety)

Reading Quran on the graves was never reported by the Prophet nor his Companions. This doesn't mean it is forbidden, at most it would be a biddah (innovations). If doing this will make your friend feel better as a way of a coping mechanism, I don't see the harm in doing so. There are many Biddah in Islam, IMO if it does not interfere with the creed and does not hurt anyone, go for it.

If anything, at minimum your friend will get rewards for reading Quran for 40 days, I do not know but I doubt your friend reads that much Quran (I know I don't) normally.

Comment: You make biddah sound harmless

Comment: Biddah can be harmless if it does not effect ones creed.

Comment: Biddah is anything above and beyond your is creed, from what I know adding to your creed is considered shirk

Answer (score 0):

Reciting Quran on the graves was never reported by the Prophet(PBH) nor his Companions. This doesn't mean it is forbidden, at most it would be a biddah (innovations). You can recite anywhere and pray for the person  who passed away. it does not depend that which place you recite. but your home or mosque are the better places for reciting the holly Quran. and one thing more, going to graveyard for 40 days was never reported too. Prophet(PBH) used to go to the graveyard, but not like we people goes, study more Hadith about this you get better understanding, we do not have to limit the Good deeds, when ever you get time recite Holly Quran and try to understand it.

Answer (score 0):

The hadith "الأرض کلھا مسجد إلا الحمام والمقبرۃ" implies the bodily and spiritual un-cleaniless of washrooms and graveyards. Hence the prohibition of acts or rituals of worship thereat.

Answer (score -2):

Praise be to Allah, the Lord of the Worlds; and may His blessings and peace be upon our Prophet Muhammad and upon all his Family and Companions.

> Muslim scholars hold different opinions as to the matter of reciting
>   the Qur'an at a grave. Some hold the opinion that it is dislikable,
>   while others say it is permissible at the time of burial. Yet, the
>   preponderant opinion, Allah Willing, is that it is not permissible at
>   the time of burial. The Prophet (peace be upon him) used to recommend
>   asking forgiveness for the dead, as stated in Saheeh Muslim, but not
>   reciting the Qur'an at the grave. As to whether the dead knows about
>   someone's supplication for him, this is affirmed, Allah willing.
>   Scholars unanimously agree that reward of charity and supplication
>   will reach the dead. As for whether the dead hear whomever addresses
>   them among the living, the most reliable opinion held by the scholars
>   is that it is true, Insha Allah (Allah Willing). Imam Ibn Taymiyah
>   (may Allah have mercy on him) said: Generally the dead person hears
>   the speech addressed to him, but not all the time; rather he may hear
>   it in certain conditions and may not in others. And this kind of
>   hearing is that of perception not response.  Ibn al-Qayyim (may Allah
>   have mercy on him) quoted Ibn Abdul-Barr as saying: It was verified
>   that the Prophet (peace be upon him) said: Whenever a Muslim passes by
>   the grave of someone whom he knows in life and salutes him (say
>   Ass-salamu Alaikum) Allah will return the soul of the dead person to
>   respond to the salutation. [Kitab Ar-Rooh (the book of the Soul) part
>   1, page: 5] Thus we advice our dear inquirer to frequently make
>   supplications, give in charity, and recite the Holy Qur'an for the
>   sake of his father. And whatever good deeds you do for your father,
>   their reward will reach him, Insha Allah. Allah knows best.

sorce : http://www.islamweb.net/emainpage/index.php?page=showfatwa&Option=FatwaId&Id=86300

Hope this can convince you about adab reading Qur'an in the grave.

Comment: I have already read this page, but I didn't find it very decisive. Do you have a good summary? Does this agree with other texts? Also this doesn't address the issue of the number associated with my issue. jazakAllah for posting this though

Comment: like the statement above I think that's is true but I'm sorry i don't have any summary or hadith which explaining about reading quran in the grave.