# Is there any reward for reciting the Quran for the dead, especially Sura Yaseen?

Tags: death, quran-recitation, reward, surat-yasin

Is there any reward for reciting the Quran for the dead, especially sura Yaseen.

This I find most of them pay to those who recite it, Mostly they will be a group of 3 guys.

Reciting Quran among those who do this action is for the person who is dead.

Is there any hadeeth to back this action?

Comment: Well i think according to sunni fiqh it's not allowed or at least makruh to earn money with Quran recitation!

Comment: See also: [After someone dies](http://islam.stackexchange.com/q/8578/9123) and [What, of reciting Quran at the grave, is permissible?](http://islam.stackexchange.com/q/4228/9123)

Comment: The sentences "This I find most of them pay to those who recite it, Mostly they will be a group of 3 guys" and "Reciting Quran among those who do this action is for the person who is dead" don't make sense to me.

Answer (score 1):

All Praise to Allah Subhanahu wa Taala and blessings on Prophet Muhammad peace be upon him His family and companions

Yeah dead ones would be rewarded from Allah Swt by His will but as mentioned by others paying the reciters is not fine.Read these to clarify it more

> قَالَ رَسُولُ اللَّهِ ـ صلى الله عليه وسلم ـ ‏ "‏ اقْرَءُوهَا عِنْدَ
> مَوْتَاكُمْ ‏"‏ ‏.‏ يَعْنِي ‏{يس}

‏ ‏

> It was narrated from Ma’qil bin Yasar that the Messenger of Allah (ﷺ)
> said: “Recite Qur’an near your dying ones,” meaning Ya-Sin.([Ibn Majah](http://www.sunnah.com/urn/1287980))

**Narrated Ma'qil ibn Yasar:
The Prophet (ﷺ) said: Recite Surah Ya-Sin over your dying men. This is the version of Ibn al-Ala'([Sunan Abi dawu](http://www.sunnah.com/abudawud/21/33)d)**

Also see this which shows very clear evidence that dead ones could receive rewards,

**'Aishah (May Allah be pleased with her) reported:
A man said to the Prophet (ﷺ): "My mother has died suddenly. I think that if she were able to talk (alive) she would have given in Sadaqah (charity). So, if I give Sadaqah now on her behalf, will she get the reward?" The Messenger of Allah (ﷺ) said, "Yes (she will be rewarded for that)."**

[[Al-Bukhari and Muslim]](https://sunnah.com/riyadussalihin:948).

The Prophet Muhammad (peace be upon him) used to go to the graves of the martyrs of Uhud once a year and also recite the verse of the Holy Quran. The Prophet Muhammad (peace be upon him) used to pray for them. When the Prophet Muhammad (peace be upon him) passed away, Abu-Bakr (Ra), Umar (Ra), Usman (Ra) and Ali (Ra) used to do the same thing.
(Tafsir Tabari, Tafsir Ibn-Kathir and Tafsir Qurtabi).

> 'Abdullah bin Abu Qatadah narrated that his father said: "The
> Messenger of Allah said: 'The best things that a man can leave behind
> are three: A righteous son who will pray for him, ongoing charity
> whose reward will reach him, and knowledge which is acted upon after
> his death.'" (Hasan) Another chain with similar wording.([Ibn
> Majah](http://www.sunnah.com/urn/1252400))

Allah Swt and His Messenger knows best.

Answer (score 0):

```
                                   In the name of Allah
```

> reciting quran after death of a person have got any reward for it?

It (getting money for reciting the Quran) is considered as a Makruh practice. In other word, it is said that Ojrah or wage of Quran reciting is counted as a Makruh act.

Or even it is narrated according to a hadith that:

> The reciter of Quran request his wage from Allah.
>   [source](http://www.wikifeqh.ir/%D8%A7%D8%AC%D8%B1%D8%AA_%D9%82%D8%B1%D8%A7%D8%A6%D8%AA_%D9%82%D8%B1%D8%A2%D9%86)

**Reference:**

[http://www.islamquest.net](http://www.islamquest.net/ar/archive/question/fa18397)

[http://www.wikifeqh.ir](http://www.wikifeqh.ir/%D8%A7%D8%AC%D8%B1%D8%AA_%D9%82%D8%B1%D8%A7%D8%A6%D8%AA_%D9%82%D8%B1%D8%A2%D9%86)

Comment: Is there any reward for reciting quran for the dead, especially sura yaseen.???

Comment: @Fajrabdulla read the stated answer from me regarding this query.

Answer (score 0):

Believe in Allah and recite whatever you want for deceased one ,pray for them specially salawaat and durood it won't be rejected ..this is the duty of Muslim to remember their Departed mates !  ,if u recite Quran with meaning n send sawab it will be more good for them according to my understanding ! Allah knows best .

Answer (score -1):

Allah knows well,

> "And that the human being can have nothing but what he has earned (good or bad)."
>   Al-Qur'an 53:39

Commenting on this ayah Ibn Kathir, rahimahullah, said, "Imam ash-Shafi'i concluded from this ayah that reciting the Qur'an does not benefit the dead, because it is not from their doing and earning. For this reason, Allah's Messenger, upon whom be peace, did not recommend it to his Ummah, encourage them to do it, or guide them to it with a text or a hint. Nor was such a thing reported from any of the sahabah. Had this been any good, they would have preceeded us in doing it. Matters of worship must be limited to the texts, and are not liable to modifications based on analogies and opinions." [Tafsir Qur'an il-'Adhim] It is in general true that one cannot benefit from other people's deeds after his death. But this has important exceptions detailed in this chapter.

Hope you understood the context. May Allah bless us all :)